# Как уменьшить макет до определенной ширины в фигме

Tags: figma

Есть макет на 1920 px c контентом и изображениями.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как уменьшить все пропорционально до 1600px вместе с шрифтами и все что в нем нарисовано?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выделяем все и держа зажатой клавишу Schift уменьшаем пропорционально, но размер шрифта придется менять руками, подстраиваясь под новый размер.